# Перевод из 16-ой системы счисления в 10-ю

Tags: c, системы-счисления

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо написать программу выполняющую данный перевод. На языке Си. Начал писать, но что-то не выполняется.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int HEX_TO_DEC(char st[10])
{
    int i, s, k, p;
    s = 0;
    p = strlen(st) - 1;
    for (i = 0; st[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        switch (toupper(st[i])) {
        case 'A':
            k = 10;
            break;
        case 'B':
            k = 11;
            break;
        case 'C':
            k = 12;
            break;
        case 'D':
            k = 13;
            break;
        case 'E':
            k = 14;
            break;
        case 'F':
            k = 15;
            break;
        case '1':
            k = 1;
            break;
        case '2':
            k = 2;
            break;
        case '3':
            k = 3;
            break;
        case '4':
            k = 4;
            break;
        case '5':
            k = 5;
            break;
        case '6':
            k = 6;
            break;
        case '7':
            k = 7;
            break;
        case '8':
            k = 8;
            break;
        case '9':
            k = 9;
            break;
        case '0':
            k = 0;
            break;
        }
        s = s + k * pow(16, p);
        p--;
    }
    printf("%s", &s ") ;
    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    char st[10];
    char ch;
    scanf (" % s ",  &st ");
    printf("Rezultant: n");
    HEX_TO_DEC(st);
}
```

В чем ошибка? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Неправильно:

```
printf( "%s",  &s");
```

Во-первых, вам даже Хэшкод подсвечивает, что кавычки как попало стоят, во-вторых, `s` - число, а выводите как строку. Попробуйте так:

```
printf( "%d",  s);
```

ну и в scanf кавычки лишние уберите.

ЗЫ Hint. Символы от A до F и 0 до 9 идут по порядку, в вашем switch нет необходимости, по крайней мере его можно сократить в 8 раз.

**upd** [вот](http://ideone.com/DgWd6) компилируемый вариант

Answer (score 4):

Попытался починить ваш код с минимумом изменений:

1. В `printf` и `scanf` лишняя кавычка перед закрывающей скобкой
2. В `printf` передавайте значение, а не адрес (лишний амперсанд)
3. В `scanf` форматная строка написана не верно, вместо `" % s "` пишите `"%s"`, оставив пробел перед модификатором, вы требуете, чтобы пробел появился при вводе, так как его нет, `scanf` считает, что разбор строки провалился и никаких присваиваний не выполнит, значит функция перевода будет работать с мусором со стека.
4. (Опционально). Переменная `ch` в функции `main` не используется, можно удалить.
5. (Опционально). Мне кажется перед выводом результата, вы хотели напечатать `"Rezultant:\n"` вместо `"Rezultant: n"`
6. (Опционально). Вы дважды подключаете `stdio.h`.

Так как входное шестнадцатеричное число подразумевается коротким (значение влезает в int), я бы воспользовался функцией `strtol()` (не забыв подключить заголовочный файл `stdlib.h`):

```
char st[10];
long result;
scanf ("%9s",  &st);
result = strtol(st, NULL, 16);
printf("Rezultant: %ld\n", result);
```

При необходимости всегда сможете проверить корректность входных данных, используя второй параметр `strtol()`. Для простоты в этом примере я его не использую.

Comment: имхо, это учебное задание на написание функции ``strtol``. понятно, что все уже написано до нас...

Comment: Наряду с strtol() на практике можно использовать sscanf (st,"%x",&s);
sscanf() возвращает количество успешно разобранных (введенных, считанных) элементов, что позволяет анализировать ощибки ввода, хотя strtol() в этом плане более гибкая функция.

Добавлю, что и strtol() и sscanf() нормально распознают вход как в формате 123, так и в формате 0x123 (иногда это удобно).

Answer (score 1):

А если так? (чуть-чуть подправил). Только переводит не из шестнадцатиричной в десятичную, а читает из шестнадцатиричного в целое беззнаковое

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void HEX_TO_DEC(char st[10])
{
    int i, k;
    unsigned int s = 0;
    for (i = 0; st[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        int c;
        switch (c = toupper(st[i]))
        {
        case 'A':
        case 'B':
        case 'C':
        case 'D':
        case 'E':
        case 'F':
            k = c - 'A' + 10;
            break;
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
        case '0':
            k = c - '0';
            break;
        }
        s = (s << 4) + k;
    }
    printf( "%u\n",  s) ;
}

void main()
{
    char st[10];
    char ch;
    unsigned int  d;
    scanf ("%9s",  st) ;
    printf ("Rezultant: ");
    HEX_TO_DEC(st);
    sscanf(st, "%x", &d);
    printf("Compare to %u\n", d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы уверены что вот это правильно:

`printf("%s, &s") ;`

?

Comment: Это не правильно.
Исправил, но все же не работает(

Answer (score 0):

Вам, наверное, сюда: [перевод из одних систем счисления в другие](http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/teornum/count_sys.php).

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы не путаться с типами, можете использовать библиотеку iostream.h, которая, по моему мнению, является более удобной, чем stdio.h.

В ней (пример):

- Ввод: `cin>>a;` // a - переменная
- Вывод: `cout<<"Переменная a - "<<a;`

Типы переменных указывать не нужно.

Comment: А теперь посмотрите на язык вопроса.